# Posting checkbox to controller MVC 5/ ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm trying to post checkbox information back to the controller so I can save update the data in the database.  Currently, I have all the values on the page, but when I check or uncheck the box it never goes to the controller.

Controller

```
[HttpPost]
public void SaveSettings(SettingsListModel SettingsModel)
{
    DataLayer dl = new DataLayer();

}
```

View

```
@model WebApplication1.Models.SettingsListModel
@{
    Layout = null;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/app.js")"></script>
    <title>Settings</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Settings</h1>
    <div>
        <form asp-action="SaveSettings" asp-controller="Home" method="post">

            <div align="center">


                <div align="center">
                    @for (int i = 0; i < Model.listOfSettings.Count; i++)
                    {
                        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.listOfSettings.ElementAt(i).settingID)
                        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.listOfSettings.ElementAt(i).settingText)

                        <div>
                            @Html.DisplayTextFor(m => m.listOfSettings.ElementAt(i).settingText)
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            //@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.listOfSettings.ElementAt(i).settingsSelected)
                            @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.listOfSettings.ElementAt(i).settingsSelected)
                        </div>
                        <br />
                        <br />
                        <br />
                    }
                </div>
            </div>
            </form>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Model

```
public class SettingsListModel
{
    public List<SettingsModel> listOfSettings { get; set; }
}

public class SettingsModel
{
    public int settingID { get; set; }

    public string settingText { get; set; }

    public bool settingsSelected { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use `.ElementAt()` in your expressions - it is generating `name` attributes that have no relationship to your model. Since the property is `List<T>`, then just use the collection indexer

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.listOfSettings.Count; i++)
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.listOfSettings[i].settingID)
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.listOfSettings[i].settingText)
    <div>
        @Html.DisplayTextFor(m => m.listOfSettings[i].settingText)
    </div>
    <div>
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.listOfSettings[i].settingsSelected)
    </div>
}
```

Your `<form>` element is also missing a submit button to post the values to the controller.

Comment: I'm trying to send it to the controller with just checking and unchecking the box.  Do I need an actual submit button?

Comment: Yes of course - that is how a form is posted to the controller method (or you could use javascript and ajax if you wanted to stay on the same page but  that does not seem appropriate in your case)

Comment: I see.  I definitely don't want to use ajax or javascript to do this.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[`Enumerable.ElementAt()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.elementat?view=netframework-4.7.2) returns a type (its return type is `TSource`), not the property name which must be added in `name` attribute. Use the collection property indexer instead:

```
<form asp-action="SaveSettings" asp-controller="Home" method="post">
    <div align="center">
    <div align="center">
    @for (int i = 0; i < Model.listOfSettings.Count; i++)
    {
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.listOfSettings[i].settingID)
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.listOfSettings[i].settingText)

        <div>
        @Html.DisplayTextFor(m => m.listOfSettings[i].settingText)
        </div>
        <div>
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.listOfSettings[i].settingsSelected)
        </div> 
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
    }
    </div>
    </div>

    <!-- add a button here to submit the form -->
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Tag helper version:

```
<form asp-action="SaveSettings" asp-controller="Home" method="post">
    <div align="center">
    <div align="center">
    @for (int i = 0; i < Model.listOfSettings.Count; i++)
    {
        <input asp-for="listOfSettings[i].settingID" type="hidden" />
        <input asp-for="listOfSettings[i].settingText" type="hidden" />

        <div>
        @Html.DisplayTextFor(m => m.listOfSettings[i].settingText)
        </div>
        <div>
        <input asp-for="listOfSettings[i].settingsSelected" type="checkbox" />
        </div> 
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
    }
    </div>
    </div>

    <!-- add a button here to submit the form -->
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Also you need to replace return type from `void` to `ActionResult` (or `IActionResult` if .NET Core is used):

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SaveSettings(SettingsListModel SettingsModel)
{
    DataLayer dl = new DataLayer();

    // do something
    return View(model);
}
```

Comment: unfortunately, it still doesn't hit the controller

Comment: I added submit button and you should change return type from `void` to `ActionResult` - because you need to redirect or return a view.